# Как выровнять текст по середине блока?

Tags: html, css

Как выровнять текст по центру блока? Для блока родителя прописано justify-content: center, но в итоге не работает, а
text-align: center выравнивает текст не так, как мне надо. В прикрепленной картинке показано, как все должно выглядеть
PS данная секция называется .features

Сам сайт ch38740.tmweb.ru

Весь код https://jsfiddle.net/0jsar8ke/

```css
.features-desc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #10375c;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="features-desc">
                    <div class="foreword">Why Frispes</div>
                    <h3>We revolutionize your workspace</h3>
                    <p>With a decade of insights and expertise, we're decided to reimagine co-working space, designed to help a new startup grow up and realize their ideas so they can give a positive impacts on many people</p>
</div>
```

Как у меня
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как надо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть мнение, что следует смотреть на line-height для тегов h3 и p, а также на margin и padding в них же.

Comment: а как line-height влияет на выравнивание по горизонтали?

Comment: по вертикали, конечно.  А что касается горизонтального выравнивания, то текст внутри `p` слева прижимается к краю самого параграфа, но справа при разной ширине окна, а значит и разной ширине параграфа слова не всегда прижимаются к самой его границе.

Comment: Добавьте к стилям `p { text-align: justify; }`

Comment: добавил, но смотрится текст некрасиво, расстояние между буквами и словами неравномерное

Comment: Или выравниваете текст по-ширине внутри тэга `p`, или выравниваете по левому краю как было изначально и миритесь с тем, что при разных разрешениях справа текст не до конца прижимается к границе параграфа, или выбираете для него фиксированную ширину, где текст смотрится идеально, но теряете адаптивность.